# Trying to share a dynamic variable between 2 controllers - Angular

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

Variable is named `searchText`and it is what will be typed in the search box by the user

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText"  placeholder=" Type KvK-nummer and Press Enter" id="typehead">
```

Example URL: `http://localhost:8091/odata/dll-poc-dv/Account('41-125061-0000') //in brackets is the searchTeaxt`

What I want to achieve is to hold the value of searchText and use in 2 different controllers to pass the searchText in URL to receive data. So I get the variable in the serivce and share that service with 2 controllers:

```
 angular.module('serviceModule',[])
        .factory('dataService',['$http', dataService]);

    function dataService($http,$rootScope,$scope){
      return{
            getSearchText:getSearchText,
            setSearchText: setSearchText,
            getMainData: getMainData
        };
     var searchText;

   function setSearchText(value){
         searchText = value;
      };
   function getSearchText(){
        return searchText;
    };

   function getMainData(id){
       return $http.get("http://localhost:8091/odata/dll-poc-dv/Account(kvk='"+id+"')").then(
            function (result){ console.debug(result);return result.data.d.results})

    };
$scope.$watch('searchText',function(newVal,oldVal){
            console.log(newVal,oldVal);
        })
};
```

First Controller:

```
    angular.module('mainPage',['serviceModule'])
      .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$http','dataService', function ($scope, $http,dataService) {

   dataService.setSearchText($scope.searchText);

    $scope.getMainData = function(kvk){ 
    $scope.getMainData = function(){
        dataService.getMainData($scope.searchText).then(function(data){
            $scope.getData= data;
        })
        };

      }]);
```

Second Controller:

```
angular.module('profileDetail',['serviceModule'])
    .controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope','$filter','$http','$q','$routeParams','dataService','moment',function($scope,$filter,$http,$q,$routeParams,dataService,moment){
        // initial grab of the right data
        function init (){

        var searchText = dataService.getSearchText();

        dataService.getMainData(searchText).then(function(data){
            $scope.getData = data;
        });
    }

     init();
    }]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you actually save the variable in the service? Since the service is a single instance and you can access that variable across controllers.

```
angular.module('app')
   .factory('dataService',['$http', dataService]);



    function dataService($http,$rootScope,$scope){
    var searchText = "";

    function setSearchText(value) {
        searchText = value;
    }

    function getSearchText() {
        return searchText;
    }

      return{
          setSearchText: setSearchText,
          getSearchText: getSearchText
      };


};
```

This way can set the variable in 1 controller then access it in another controller with the service methods, no need to have any rootScope stuff going on.

So in the **Controller A** you can set the variable first -

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .controller('ControllerA', ['dataService', ControllerA]);

function ControllerA(dataService) {
    var vm = this;

    // Set the variable from this controller
    dataService.setSearchText("blabla");

};
})(window.angular);
```

Then access it in **Controller B** -

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .controller('ControllerB', ['dataService', ControllerB]);

function ControllerB(dataService) {
    var vm = this;

    // Set the variable from this controller
    var searchText = dataService.getSearchText();

};
})(window.angular);
```

plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/iO7QTY7OBYLEqGuIhCJO?p=preview

Comment: I am still getting empty strings from the service, althought controller A works and sets it, but somehow A its not getting the value from controllerB

Comment: I've just created a plnkr showing how it works, there must definetly be an issue with your code somewhere.

Comment: I know it should work, so I edited my code above. Please take a look if I am doing it right now. First Controller is working fine, but second controller only showing initial value from service, not the one set in controller A

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint to see if the setMethod of the dataService is actually getting triggered, what is coming into the method and also what is going out of the getMethod?

Comment: I am watching searchText inside factory, but the methods are not working. Old and newVal are both undefined(inital value inside factory).

Comment: Then there is the problem, ok I'm updating my answer to reflect the changes. You need to cut out the serviceModule because you're not able to acces its factories like that I guess. Just have dataService as a factory to the app.

Comment: calling the set function inside getMainData method of dataService worked. Thanks for the help